# What's the difference between a temporary #Stored procedure vs a phisical proc in terms of performance or execution plan?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-execution-plan

main difference between those database objects

Comment: Wow, didn't even know temporary stored procedures exists! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary stored procedures are like normal stored procedures but, as their name suggests, have fleeting existence.

Since they are created in tempdb, they can be called from any database. SQL Server basically ignores database name and schema name in the case of temporary stored procedures.

Heavy use of temporary stored procedures can create contention on system tables in tempdb. But useful when connecting to earlier versions of SQL server that do not support reuse of execution plans for T-SQL statement or batches.

In terms of performance and execution plan, both normal and temporary stored procedures work the same way.

You can find more on this article. 
[Temporary Stored Procedures](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Temporary+Stored+Procedures./99822/)